# Pick an element from included PHP using Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have been making a website that has lots of pages. Hence decided to put the navigation bar in a separate php file to reduce re-work in all those pages in case of changes. So in my `index.php` I have included the navigation bar like:

```
<?php include 'navbar.php'; ?>
```

And the navbar.php looks like:

```
<div id="nav"> 
<ul>
<li pg="#home" >home</li>
<li pg="#pack" >packages</li>
<li pg="#about" >about</li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

In the index.php, I have a javascript onClick function to select the `<li>` from navbar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var oldpg = "#home";
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#nav ul li').click(function() {
//here are the codes to hide/show divs });

});
</script>
```

But when you click those `<li>` nothing happens. I think the js is not picking up the elements from the php. How can I refer to those elements in a separate php file?

Comment: How do you know "nothing happens" ? **what** is not happening?

Comment: It can't be just because they're from PHP.  PHP executes on the server side, it assembles the entire document and then sends it to the user.  By the time javascript executes on the client side, it's all a single document, so there's no distinction as to what elements came from a different php file.

Comment: And a minor point, but when you add custom attributes to a tag, it's customary to prefix them with "data-", so you'd want `<li data-pg=...`.  But that's obviously not the problem.

Comment: But general debugging checks; view source, make sure the desired elements are actually in the source code.  Look at a console (press F12 in Chrome, for example) make sure you're not getting any console errors that would indicate the problem.

Comment: @Sergio I have written codes to hide/show divs inside the `onClick` function. Tried with just plain `Alert` function too, no good.
@Retsam I did check everything from Firebug. As you said, the page is loading things fine and good. Only the JS is not working.

Comment: Something else is amiss here. Can you add your entire navbar.php to pastebin and then add the entire html document to jsfiddle?

Comment: @Win32.tr0jan, can you post this code: `//here are the codes to hide/show divs });`, and what is `pg`/`oldpg`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` and try. Not tested but that may be the problem here. Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on('click', '#nav ul li', function(e) {
  //Your code
 });
});
```

Also make sure that you included `jQuery` library

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why does it make difference if it loaded with php with pageload?

Comment: included content is not "dynamic" as far as the browser is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

The code you showed us is correct. As long as the [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/div.html) with id "nav" is indeed being displayed, make sure you are including the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library correctly. If it is, your error must reside inside whatever you did *inside* the click event handler [`$.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) (in `//here are the codes to hide/show divs`).

Comment: @Retsam Maybe his problem is that he's not including the jQuery library or that he has an error inside the event handler, but that's just my guess.

Comment: Code is _almost_ correct :) You fixed it in your fiddle Edit: @Retsam fixed it in fiddle

Comment: @Campari I tried with `alert` function, its not working. And jQuery is working as I am using `Spritley` plugin to pan some images. 
@Retsam It is working if you put the navbar inside the html than in php.

Comment: @Win32.tr0jan Look at Retsam's fiddle. Apparently it _is_ working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav ul li').click(function() {
  //here are the codes to hide/show divs });

  });
}); // you left off this closing
```

You can use Chrome DevTools or Firebug to view the console.

Comment: it's there, just commented

Comment: Right, the question is whether it's also commented in his version, or if that was a transcription error when posting to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for replying @Retsam @Campari @Chris @Ankit

As @Retsam said, I tried with Chrome console and found the error to be 
`Uncaught reference error: $ not defined` (Firebug console didn't give any error/message)
The reason was because I had put my code before linking with the jQuery library.
So I moved my

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

above the `onClick` function and it worked.

Silly me ...

Thanks guys